# Systems similar to TI's PRUs

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, texas-instruments, beaglebone-black

I have been working with [TI's PRUs](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/PRU-ICSS) on the am335x, equipped on the BeagleBone Black. I would like to know if other hardware manufactures offer similar systems. I am doing my Bachelor Thesis on this topic. So, it would be nice if I had some other system to compare to.

So far I have found nothing like it. The BeagleBone Black seems to be somewhat of a hybrid between a Raspberry Pi and an Arduino.

**Edit:**
I'm not looking for a recommendation to buy anything. For my thesis I need to compare the system that I'm using with their possible competitors. I think it's interesting to know what systems are out there apart form the one that I'm working with (the am335x).

Comment: Not sure if it is what you're looking for, but there are some multi-core MCUs which include a low-end Cortex-M, in addition to a bigger core, to solve the same kind of real-time problems PRUs are meant to solve. Look at LPC43xx, MAC57D5xx, STM32WB, VF6xx, ...

Comment: The equivalent competitors with high-end Cortex-A seem to be [Renesas RZ](https://www.renesas.com/eu/en/products/microcontrollers-microprocessors/rz.html) and [NXP QuorIQ](https://www.nxp.com/products/processors-and-microcontrollers/arm-based-processors-and-mcus/qoriq-layerscape-arm-processors:QORIQ-ARM). They seem to be the same high-end, general-purpose SoC product lines. Though note that if links like these answer your question, that's a strong indication that this is an off-topic shopping recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NXP's S12X series of processors has an "XGATE coprocessor to achieve higher performance or emulate peripheral modules"...

https://www.nxp.com/products/processors-and-microcontrollers/additional-processors-and-mcus/8-16-bit-mcus/16-bit-s12-and-s12x-mcus:S12S12X

They (NXP) also have various processors that include eTPUs (Enhanced Time Processor Units)...

https://www.nxp.com/products/processors-and-microcontrollers/power-architecture-processors/mpc5xxx-55xx-32-bit-mcus/ultra-reliable-mpc56xx-32-bit-automotive-and-industrial-microcontrollers-mcus/enhanced-time-processor-unit:eTPU

Comment: XGATE isn't a real multi-core though, it's a co-processor used to offload interrupt handling from the main CPU. I'm not certain if it can actually be used to run multiple processes. At any rate the S12 is a legacy 16 bitter which can by no means be compared with a bloody Cortex A8/A9 RISC! MPC56 is more in line, but still not in the same genre - they would be the equivalents of TI Hercules.

Comment: "_XGATE isn't a real multi-core though, it's a co-processor used to offload interrupt handling from the main CPU._" - a bit like a PRU then?

Comment: I don't really know what a "PRU" is supposed to be, but I can click on the datasheet and see a monstrous Sitara A8 with support for graphics acceleration and higher level fieldbus protocols. That's an entirely different task compared to offloading various low level interrupts of 16 bit MCU to a co-processor. It's not anywhere near the same genre. They can't be compared, as it would be comparing apples vs bicycles. Suggesting to a student that they should make a thesis based on such a comparison isn't helpful.

Comment: Ah! Maybe _Ludin_ and I are interpreting _jpuriol_'s "similar systems" differently... I am interpreting "similar systems" to mean "core + general purpose coprocessor(s)", since PRUs were specifically mentioned in the question, whereas _Ludin_ seems to be interpreting "similar systems" to mean "Cortex A8 genre + graphics + fieldbus interfaces". Only _jpuriol_ knows what he really meant.

Comment: I meant "core + general purpose coprocessor(s) specifically designed for Real-time tasks". PRU stands for Programmable Real-time Unit, it's a 32 bit RISC core with no pipeline and single-cycle execution. The PRU cores are completely deterministic. [This document](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sprace9/sprace9.pdf) document is helpful understand what PRU actually are (at least to myself). Thanks for your input @Lundin and @strl100!

Comment: @jpuriol All CPU cores tend to be deterministic... that pdf doesn't really say jack except "this is a fast dual core thing that can be used in many ways". All ARM are RISC. PRU seems to be mostly a TI term. As mentioned, your AM335x has very little in common with S12X and not much with MPC56. Renesas RZ and NPX QorIQ seem to be the most prominent competitors.

Comment: @Ludin After taking a look at your links I think the most similar thing to TI's PRUs it's the [RZ/T1](https://www.renesas.com/eu/en/products/microcontrollers-microprocessors/rz/rzt/rzt1.html) What do you think?